# Questions regarding geodesics in Adler and Taylor's "Random Fields and Geometry"

Tags: stochastic-processes, stationarity, geometry, random-field

I'm working through some calculations in Adler & Taylor's *Random Fields and Geometry*. $f$ is a real, scalar, zero-mean random field parametrized by $x^i$ (elements of some topological space $T$). Using commas to denote partial derivatives $f_{,i} \equiv \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$ and angle brackets for expectations (with respect to the probability space of $f$, $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$, so $\langle g(f) \rangle \equiv \int_\Omega g(f)p(f)df$), the metric induced by $f$ is given by
$$
g_{ij} = \langle f_{,i}f_{,j}\rangle
$$
and the Christoffel symbols are
$$
\Gamma_{ijk}=\langle f_{,i}f_{,jk}\rangle.
$$
I thought I'd see what the standard geodesic equation from differential geometry looks like, since it's not in the text. The text only says "the geodesic between two points on $M$ is the curve along which the expected variance of the derivative of $f$ is minimized."

Parametrizing $x^i$ by path length $l$ and using dots for derivatives, $\dot{x}^i \equiv \frac{d x^i}{dl}$, the geodesic equation is:
\begin{align}
0 &= \ddot{x}^i + \Gamma^i_{jk} \dot{x}^j\dot{x}^k \\
&= \frac{d^2x^i}{dl^2} + \Gamma^i_{jk}\frac{dx^j}{dl}\frac{dx^k}{dl} \\
&= \frac{d^2x^i}{dl^2} + g^{is}\Gamma_{sjk}\frac{dx^j}{dl}\frac{dx^k}{dl} \\
&= \frac{d^2x^i}{dl^2} + g^{is}\left\langle f_{,s} f_{,jk}\right\rangle\frac{dx^j}{dl}\frac{dx^k}{dl} \\
&= \frac{d^2x^i}{dl^2} + g^{is}\left\langle f_{,s}\left(\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^j \partial x^k}\frac{dx^j}{dl}\frac{dx^k}{dl}\right)\right\rangle \\
&= \frac{d^2x^i}{dl^2} + g^{is}\left\langle f_{,s}\left(\frac{d^2f}{dl^2} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}\frac{d^2x^j}{dl^2}\right)\right\rangle \\
&= \frac{d^2x^i}{dl^2} + g^{is}\left\langle f_{,s}\ddot{f}\right\rangle - g^{is}\left\langle f_{,s}f_{,j}\right\rangle \frac{d^2x^j}{dl^2} \\
&= \frac{d^2x^i}{dl^2} + g^{is}\left\langle f_{,s}\ddot{f}\right\rangle - g^{is}g_{sj}\frac{d^2x^j}{dl^2} \\
&= \frac{d^2x^i}{dl^2} + g^{is}\left\langle f_{,s}\ddot{f}\right\rangle - \delta^i_j \frac{d^2x^j}{dl^2} \\
&= \frac{d^2x^i}{dl^2} + g^{is}\left\langle f_{,s}\ddot{f}\right\rangle - \frac{d^2x^i}{dl^2} \\
&= g^{is}\left\langle f_{,s}\ddot{f}\right\rangle \\
&= \left\langle f^{,i}\ddot{f}\right\rangle. \\
\end{align}
Contracting with $g_{im}$, we get $\left \langle f_{,m} \ddot{f} \right\rangle = 0$. (We could have done this at the start).

Contracting again with $\dot{x}^m$, we get $\left\langle f_{,m}\ddot{f}\right\rangle\dot{x}^m = \left\langle \dot{f}\ddot{f} \right\rangle = 0$.

---

#### Questions

1. Any gross errors here?
2. What assumptions am I using?
3. Any interpretations, applications, or examples?
4. What does this tell us about stationarity along the path?

Comment: What are the expectations taken with respect to? Line 6 is clever, but it requires line 5, which I'm confused with. Why can $\dot{x}^j$ and $\dot{x}^k$ be taken inside the expectation? Are they independent of the variables you're taking the EV WRT?

Comment: @Bridgeburners

I've explained more about $x^i$ and $\langle \cdots\rangle$ in the text.

So I've assumed I can move the $\dot{x}$s inside the expectation to show the step from line 5 to 6. Can I get from line 4 to 7 without it?

Unless I'm mistaken, the only thing random here is $f$, and the expectations are taken with respect to its probability space. So I don't think the expectation integral acts on the $x^i$ (it would have to be by way of $f^{-1}$?).

Line 6 happens by the chain rule of ordinary calculus (with $f = f(x^i(l))$).